# Django: Reverse M2M query with a "through" model

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-queryset

I have the following setup:

```
class Ride(models.Model):
   ...
   riders = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='RideRiders', null=True, blank=True)

   class Meta:
        db_table    = 'rides'
        app_label   = 'rides'


class RideRiders(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)
   ride = models.ForeignKey(Ride)

   # Other information
   ...

   class Meta:
       db_table    = 'rides_riders'
       app_label   = 'rides'
```

So, for example, i can get all the rides for a user using the following (is this actually the best way?):

```
Ride.objects.filter(riders__id=user_id)
```

I want to be able to get all the users for a particular ride but can't seem to figure out how. This RideRiders model seems to be the sticking point as i can't seem to pass beyond that to the user. For example:

```
Ride.objects.get(id=ride_id).riders.all()
```

...gives a list of RideRider objects (i think).

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
To add more context, i'm attempting to fetch the riders for a particular ride as an API call using the Django Rest Framework. This is how i'm using it:

```
class RideRiders(generics.ListAPIView):
   model = User
   serializer_class = RiderSerializer

   def get_queryset(self):
       return Ride.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get('id')).riders.all()
```

But this is currently giving me the error which is why i feel it's returning RideRider objects rather than Rider objects.

```
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword u'ride' into field. Choices are: date_joined, email, first_name, groups, id, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, password, user_permissions, username
```

EDIT 2:
So `Ride.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get('id')).riders.all()` is throwing the above error (nothing to do with serializers as thought). If i run `Ride.objects.get(id=self.kwargs.get('id')).rideriders_set.all()` then it returns a queryset (and testing gives the expected number of records for any particular ride). So, this leaves the original question of how do i return a list of users (rather than RideRider objects)?

Comment: yes, `Ride.objects.get(id=ride_id).riders.all()` gives you the queryset you are looking for (all the users for that particular ride, provided that ride exists, of course)

Comment: in order to get all the rides for a specific user you'd use the `related field` named `ride_set`. You can customize it using the related_name argument in the field. Please see here for a full explanation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/

Comment: and here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

Comment: Thanks for this. I've edited the question to add some context. The error that i'm ultimately getting suggests to me that a field containing a ride object is making its way through to the serializer which is why i'm not sure if i'm actually getting User objects back.

Comment: you seem to be using the wrong combination of model (User) and serializer (RiderSerializer).

Comment: assuming RiderSerializer serializes the Ride model, that is not what you want to return. You need to return (serialize) Users. So `serializer_class = UserSerializer' should do. Obviously you will need to define it and customize it to suit your needs (i.e. fields, references, etc).

Comment: Ok, so we're ahead of where we need to be. It appears that the above error is being thrown when we call `Ride.objects.get(id=ride_id).riders.all()`, so well before the serializer.

Comment: Also, RiderSerializer serializer the User model (the terms User and Rider are used for the same model). It's a tad confusing i know.

Comment: OK the error message shows fields belonging to the user, presumably stored in the through table. So you need to apply a Serializer to that model, returning a couple of fields (id and link to the user detail)

Comment: I've realised this error isn't to do with the serializer. See my latest edit to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The culprit turned out to be `app_label   = 'rides'` in the model classes was incorrect after some refactoring of the overall application. This was clearly stopping Django from making the proper lookups across models as they weren't being registered properly.